# Sequence of leading spaces not being ignored when setting IFS to null

Tags: bash

As per the manual:

```
If IFS is unset, or its value
       is exactly <space><tab><newline>, the default, then sequences of
       <space>, <tab>, and <newline> at the beginning and end of the
       results of the previous expansions are ignored, and any sequence
       of IFS characters not at the beginning or end serves to delimit
       words.
```

And:

```
If
       the value of IFS is null, no word splitting occurs.
```

What I take from this:
If IFS is null, then wordsplitting does not occur and hence sequences of leading space, tabs, and newlines aren't ignored.

If this statement is true, then why does
`IFS= echo sssssssssssssssXYZ` print
`XYZ` instead of `sssssssssssssssXYZ` with `s` being the space character

is it because this affects only the results of the parameter expansion, command expansion, and arithmetic expansion?

If so, then still, why does echo not print the leading space characters?

Comment: There is no expansion in your example command. The text that you quote from does not apply. Try it again with a variable: `v='          XYZ'; echo $v`

Comment: `echo "sssssXYZ"` will retain the spaces. With `echo sssssXYZ`, the shell syntax itself permits whitespace between most keywords, so the initial command parsing discards whitespace. IFS only comes into play with specific built-in commands.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A number of reasons.

First is that word splitting only happens, and `IFS` only applies, on the results of expansions, not on text directly on the command line(*). Splitting the command line to words is different, and consecutive unquoted spaces are same as one there. In `somecmd foo:bar`, `somecmd` gets one argument, and in `somecmd foo bar`, it gets two arguments, regardless of if `IFS` contains a colon or space. And in `echo        xyz`, `echo` gets the single argument `xyz`.

Second is that the value of `IFS` set before parsing starts on the command line is what matters. If we set `var=foo:bar` and then run `IFS=: printf "%s\n" $var`, `printf` still gets *one* argument after the format string, and the output is `foo:bar` on one line. The variable setting on the same command only applies within that command, *inside* it, and `printf` or `echo` don't use `IFS`.

We'd have to set `IFS` on an earlier command have it apply, e.g. this would print `foo` and `bar` on two separate lines: `var=foo:bar IFS=:; printf "%s\n" $var`. And this would keep the spaces: `var="     foo" IFS=:; printf "%s\n" $var`.

Though, in a lot of cases, it's better to just quote expansion, as that will protect the results from word splitting *and* globbing, regardless of the value of `IFS`.

<sub>(* AFAIK in some early shell(s) `IFS` did apply to words directly on the command line. Setting `IFS=b` would make `echo foobar` print `foo ar`.)</sub>

Comment: The second paragraph about IFS being set before parsing starts and how the builtins print and echo don't use it. I never knew that was a thing. I have read the full Bash manual and I either overlooked the text describing that or that text didn't exist in the manual. Could you refer to me some sources, documentation, or books that I could use to gain a deeper knowledge of the shell's behaviors?

Comment: @IFS_eating_away_at_my_soul, other than http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide and and [the tag wiki for bash here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tags/bash/info) (and the top questions), not really.

Comment: @IFS_eating_away_at_my_soul, the value of IFS used follows (if nothing else) from the process for execution of simple commands, the [POSIX text](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_01) lists the steps as 1. save variable assignments for later, 2. expand other words (this is where word splitting happens), 3. redirections, 4. expand variable assignments (setting the new value of IFS).

Comment: In an assignment like `IFS=: echo $var` the new value is also not visible in the shell on subsequent commands, so there, too, you can think of that as affecting just the _command_, not the _shell_. Because, they are different. The shell does some processing on the command line, and then it runs the command. (It doesn't matter if it's actually builtin to the shell, the rules are the same (some special cases may apply)). When `printf` or `echo` runs, the command line has already gone through word splitting, there's no need for them to use `IFS`.

Comment: But `read` _does_ use `IFS`, it does splitting internally, on the value it read _itself_. It doesn't get that preprocessed on the command line .

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot and I have another question @ilkkachu. The manual states that as long as there exists an "IFS whitespace character" in the value of IFS, then sequences of leading and trailing whitespace, tabs, and newlines get deleted. My question to you is, what exactly is an IFS whitespace character? Is it one of whitespace, tab, or newline? So, having any one of these characters in IFS's value will make sure that IFS will follow the default behavior of stripping trailing and leading spaces?

Comment: @IFS_eating_away_at_my_soul, it says it there in the full sentence, though the structure is a bit awkward: _"then sequences of the whitespace characters space, tab, and newline are ignored at the beginning and end of the word, as long as the whitespace character is in the value of IFS (an IFS whitespace character)"_. I think those three are what the shell considers as whitespace (e.g. a carriage return isn't), and the ones that happen to be in IFS are "IFS whitespace". If you set `IFS=$'\t:'` (tab and colon), then leading tabs are ignored, but leading colons generate empty fields.

Comment: set `IFS=$'\t:' var1=$'\t\tfoo' var2=$'::foo'` and compare `printf "<%s>\n" $var1` vs `printf "<%s>\n" $var2`

Comment: Ok, I see thanks a lot again for your great insights! I actually made notes of everything you said so I can commit it to memory. @ilkkachu